# When I am repeatedly working with WebBrowser.Document.DomDocument I get OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, dom, webbrowser-control

When I am repeatedly working with WebBrowser.Document.DomDocument I get OutOfMemoryException.

In my console app I have following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public class OutOfMem
    {
        static private List<string> List = new List<string>();
        private const string _url = "http://www.google.com";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // in i == 86 out of mem exception
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TestFunc));
                t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                t.Start();
                t.Join();
                t = null;
            }
        }

        private static void TestFunc()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
            wb.Navigate(_url);

            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                Application.DoEvents();

            wb.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);

            mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = wb.Document.DomDocument as mshtml.HTMLDocument;

            // this throws out of memory exception when i == 86 why?
            string html = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
            doc.close();

            // trying to release everything
            wb.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.Collect();
        }

        private static void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlDocument document = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document;
            mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = document.DomDocument as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
            List.Add(doc.documentElement.outerHTML);
            doc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And I get OutOfMemory Exception. I don’t know what I should release but I don’t. It seems that program doesn’t take too much memory (check just via Windows Task Manager). I am using VS 2012 under W7.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend to call List.Add for every iteration through the loop without ever clearing the list? By run 86, you have 86 copies of the outerHTML.

Comment: Yes, that's what is done and I don't think a few strings (which in case of my example are quite small) should be reason for out of memory exception...